# Count not returning total count value in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, count

I have a MySQL database and it has a signUp table. The table has a field called created which is a placeholder for signups date. Format is eg: [2014-10-12 17:48:24].

There are many user who signup in single day. I am trying to get a count of each **day** signups.

My code below displays single date eg: [20141012000000] but the count is still 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNCATE(created,-6) as created, 
       COUNT(*) as CountCreated 

FROM signUp 

WHERE created >= '20000101000000' AND created <= '30000101000000' 

GROUP BY created

---SQL RESULT---

|------------------------|-------------------------|
|Created                      CountCreated
|------------------------|-------------------------|
|20141012000000                  1
|------------------------|-------------------------|
|20141015000000                  1                
|------------------------|-------------------------|
```

There are more than 30 signup for that date.
I used truncate so that the value is compared at the WHERE statement and its ommiting the **TIME** and only returning **DATE**. The time is zeroed.

**What I am trying to get:**

I simply want to get the total count of created field for that date. For example my signUp for [20141012000000] is 30 so I need it like this

```
|------------------------|-------------------------|
|Created                      CountCreated
|------------------------|-------------------------|
|20141012000000                  30
|------------------------|-------------------------|
|20141015000000                  33                
|------------------------|-------------------------|
```

Please help me fix this...

Thank You.

Comment: What is the data type of `created`?

Comment: created is a DATE(timestamp) type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Your solution worked. Could you please tell me why my query was not working and giving only 1 count?

Comment: . . The fundamental problem is `group by created` which essentially creates a separate group for each date/time.  You want a separate group for each date.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `created` is `datetime`:

```
SELECT date(created) as created,  COUNT(*) as CountCreated 
FROM signUp 
GROUP BY date(created);
```

If it is a string:

```
SELECT left(created, 10) as created,  COUNT(*) as CountCreated 
FROM signUp 
GROUP BY left(created, 10);
```

Comment: I think in the second edition it should be left(created, 8) instead of left(created, 10) isn't!? (with regard to sample data in question)

Comment: @Farhęg . . . That's funny.  I wrote the question with 8 and then re-read the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You'd also have to group by the truncated value in that scenario, and then get rid of the distinct. But a better option would simply be to make the created field a timestamp, and then use date(created).